# Entity Framework not updating record in the method

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I'm using the EF with my ASP.NET MVC website and I notice a 'problem' in one new `actionresult()` method.

In the same Action I have two operations in the same Test table.

Code:

```
  //Break point 01
 _documentRepository.UpdateStatus(documentToUpload.IDDocument, Status.Admin);

 //Break point 02 - Just create this aux var to break here and check the database.
 var aux = 1;

  //Break point 03
 var documents =  documentRepository.GetByID(documentToUpload.IDProtocol).ToList();
 foreach(var doc in documents)
 {  
    if(doc.Status == Status.Admin)
    { 
       //Break point 04
       //Never Breaks here.
    }
 }
```

When the ***Break point 02*** fires I go to the database and check the status of the Document, and it is already equals **Status.Admin** (as I changed in the break point 01 code). But when I get a list of documents, I check in this list and the document still with the older status.

What it could be?

EDIT:

Repository code:

```
    public IEnumerable<Document> GetByID(Guid idProtocol)
    {
        return _context.Document.Where(d => d.IDProtocol.Equals(idProtocol));
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure that the document you update is in the list returned by `documentRepository.GetByID()`?

Comment: Probably need to show some of your repository code so that folks can see how you are handling your EF context(s).

Comment: @ledbutter Yes, i am, becouse i expand the list and check the IDs of the documents.

Comment: @DavidTansey i made a edit in the OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I´ve found the solution, it was I mistake that i made. I was using the same repository object to do both operations. I create a new DocumentRepository object inside the Action method and use it to get the list of documents, then i got the list update.